# swrevealviewcontroller shifts the view

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to use swrevealviewcontroller library with swift 3 to make slide menu.

```
menuButton = UIBarButtonItem( title: "Menu", style:  UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)) )
```

it works, but when the menu view appears, the main view shifts down, and after there menu view is closed, items bar of the main view shifts back , and the content of the view remains on the same position so that a gap between the items bar and content (in my case - table view) appears.

Are there any parameters in SWRevealViewController.m which allow to open menu without moving the main view down?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Main view controller hides status bar with

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

while menu view controller doesn't. Adding this code to menu view controller fixes the problem, as status bar wouldn't  appear and items bar  and main view controller's content would stay on the same y coordinate .